# Not authorization on FacebookApp, calling from my iOS App with FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I create an iOS app with Facebook SDK to use FB-login to authenticate.

The app was working on devices correctly.

However, sometimes the app is NOT working well when using openWithCompletionHandler (Using FacebookSDK) in recent days.
I aware it last week (on Jul.5th).

The issue is that FBSession openWithCompletionHandler isn't calling the completion handler.

Rountine to auth with FBApp on my app
 1. My app need to login into Facebook for authorization.
 2. Call 'openWithCompletionHandler' then open FacebookApp to auth
 3. (*) Not authorization on FBApp, show up ordinary Facebook (appear user's feed).
 4. Doesn't go back to my app.

I'm bothering this issue.
Actually, 3rd line (*), FacebookApp begin to authenticate my app and then callback with openWithCompletionHandler.

Why sometimes it's not working well in recent days.
I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook SDK is really crappy. I used a Backend as a Service Provider as a workaround. It's called [apiomat](http://www.apiomat.om) Pretty easy and fast.